# Display html hover over an image

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display rendered HTML content when I hover over an image. For instance

```
<img src="test.jpg" onmouseover="show('<b>This is bold text</b>')" onmouseout="hidetext()" />
```

I would like the content to follow my mouse as it hovers as well. With the code I have for some reason the hover over html tends to blink as I move the mouse over. Any ideas why this is happening? Seems to be smoother in some browsers like Chrome and FF but IE is way choppy.

Example: torhead.com/items put your mouse over any of the items

Comment: Do you have any more idea of what you want?  Can you describe what you mean a little better?  Do you mean you want some HTML element hovering and covering the image?  Or just something arbitrarily appearing on the page?

Answer (score 6):

Any number of ways. Here's one off the top of my sleep-deprived head:

```
<img src="test.jpg" class="hastooltip" />
<div>
    This is the HTML content to show when the image is moused over.
    It will appear just to the bottom-right of the image (though this can be changed)
</div>
```

Then in your stylesheet:

```
.hastooltip + div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -50px;
    Adjust and un-comment these margins to move the tooltip */
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}
.hastooltip:hover + div, .hastooltip + div:hover { display: block; }
```

Bingo. No JavaScript required ;)

Comment: Sorry should have explained more detail, I want it to rollover following my mouse

Comment: Well that's where things get more complicated. Thankfully there's lots of examples on Google. Sorry, too tired to be much help right now =_=-(zzz)

Comment: I freakin love this site way more than experts-exchange.com I get answers way faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to just display a tooltip? In that case, a "title" attribute would be sufficient:

```
<img src="test.jpg" title="<html></html"  />
```

Comment: The title will show html and render it as html? But I would like it to  follow the mouse as well

Comment: What do you mean by "follow the mouse"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery plugin like these here: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/14-jquery-plugins-for-working-with-images/

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want, with the tooltip moving with the mouse cursor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTooltip(e, tooltip)
    {
        e = window.event ? window.event : e;
        tooltip = document.getElementById(tooltip);
        if(tooltip.style.display != "block")
            tooltip.style.display = "block";
        tooltip.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
        tooltip.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    }

    function hideTooltip(e, tooltip)
    {
        e = window.event ? window.event : e;
        tooltip = document.getElementById(tooltip);
        if(e.toElement == tooltip)
        {
            showTooltip(e, tooltip);
            return;
        }
        tooltip.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<div>
<img alt="" src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" class="hastooltip"  onmousemove="showTooltip(event, 'dvTooltip');" onmouseout="hideTooltip(event, 'dvTooltip');" />

<div id="dvTooltip" style="display:none;position:absolute;background-color:#fff;" onmousemove="showTooltip(event, 'dvTooltip');">
    This <b>is</b> <i>HTML</i>.
</div>
```

Comment: you rock man, I am getting a flickering issue with the rollover can you check it out? http://www.swtorprogress.com/characters/?id=109 put your mouse over the 50x50 image to the left of the character

Comment: I have edited it to fix the flicker and follow issue, by adding an onmousemove event to the tooltip div as well :)

Comment: So the flickering is still happening, but I have narrowed it down to when I mouse down or right, if I mouse up and left no flicker lol

Comment: Can you make it so the bottom left of the tooltip follows the top right of the mouse?

Comment: Yes, you just need to adjust the last line in showTooltip() to:

    tooltip.style.bottom = event.clientY + "px"